# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0. When running react-native run-android

Tags: android, macos, react-native, gradle

```
react-native info:{
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.6
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
    Memory: 39.49 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.18.2 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 6.14.5 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.9.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 14.3, DriverKit 20.2, macOS 11.1, tvOS 14.3, watchOS 7.2
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 4.1 AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283
    Xcode: 12.3/12C33 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 14.0.2 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
    react-native: 0.63.4 => 0.63.4 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
}

Error: {
 Task :app:packageDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.

Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
}
```

This error happened after trying to run react-native run-android on a physical android device. Now my emulators won't even work.

I have cleaned my Gradle and have tried running directly from android studio. Any idea what may be the issue? I notice that my android environment is not found in my react-native info. Not sure if this is an indication of what may be wrong.

Comment: this  "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0." is simply a warning that "breaking" changes are to come, based on the gradlew environment setup - it prints whether a task is successful or not. If you type : `./gradlew --version` it will probably have `6.x.x`.  your actual problem is : `Android SDK: Not Found` - as per the message in the error.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I created a new project with react-native init and the android version works fine, what do you think might be the cause? I haven't added any new packages between now and when it began to crash, only tried to run the app on a physical android device.

Answer (score -1):

<sub>(Reposting solution on behalf of the question author, to move it to the answer space.)</sub>

Not sure what exactly went wrong but cleaning my Gradle and resetting cache in RN fixed it this morning. I did all of these things before posting here yesterday which didn't work so I'm not sure why everything is fine today. May be because of my PC's reboot, cleaning Gradle and cache.